# Adding different colours to nav elements

Tags: html, css, nav

I'm looking to add different background colours to each of the Option's on my secondary nav. I've tried a few things but it just bloats up the code beyond belief. There has to be an easier way. Thanks in advance.

http://codepen.io/Compton/pen/hlrId

```
<div class="container">
            <section> <!--class="color-4"-->
                <nav class="cl-effect-2">
                    <a href="#"><span data-hover="Option 1">Option 1</span></a>
                    <a href="#"><span data-hover="Option 2">Option 2</span></a>
                    <a href="#"><span data-hover="Option 3">Option 3</span></a>
                    <a href="#"><span data-hover="Option 4">Option 4</span></a>
                    <a href="#"><span data-hover="Option 5">Option 5</span></a>
                    <a href="#"><span data-hover="Option 6">Option 6</span></a>
                </nav>
            </section>
        </div><!-- /container -->

*,
*:after,
*::before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    margin: 100px 0 0 0 !important;
}
/* Effect 2: 3D rolling links, idea from http://hakim.se/thoughts/rolling-links */
.cl-effect-2 a {
    line-height: 44px;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    -moz-perspective: 1000px;
    perspective: 1000px;
}

.cl-effect-2 a span {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 14px;
    background: #231f20;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
    transform-origin: 50% 0;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.csstransforms3d .cl-effect-2 a span::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    content: attr(data-hover);
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: background 0.3s;
    transition: background 0.3s;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
    transform-origin: 50% 0;
}

.cl-effect-2 a:hover span,
.cl-effect-2 a:focus span {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-22px);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-22px);
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-22px);
}

.csstransforms3d .cl-effect-2 a:hover span::before,
.csstransforms3d .cl-effect-2 a:focus span::before {
    background: #231f20;    
}

nav a {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 15px 78px;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    font-size: 1.35em;
}

nav a:hover,
nav a:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like [***this***](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DdblA) for each one of those options

```
[data-hover="Option 1"],
[data-hover="Option 1"]::before
{
  background-color:red!important;
}
```

Obviously, if you're more specific with your selectors, you can do away with `!important` but this should give you an idea.

---

## Update:

I see what you meant now.

Try [***this***](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pHxzf) then

```
.cl-effect-2 a span[data-hover="Option 1"],
.csstransforms3d .cl-effect-2 a:hover span[data-hover="Option 1"]::before,
.csstransforms3d .cl-effect-2 a:focus span[data-hover="Option 1"]::before
{
  background-color:#c00;
}
```

What happened before was caused by the `!important` declaration from before which overrode the transition colour

And if you want to change the transition colour too. Just add this before the last rule. [***DEMO***](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ehBqp)

```
.csstransforms3d .cl-effect-2 a span[data-hover="Option 1"]::before
{
  background-color:orange;
}
```

Comment: Okay, this definitely is a fall back that I'd be happy with. Is it possible to maintain the colour balance on animate? Each element has three colour states.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you can have the `span` and its `::before` have different colours like [**this**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/niaEc)

Comment: If you check my original pen http://codepen.io/Compton/pen/hlrId you can see black as it flips. It starts with #231f20, flips or hovers on #000 and ends up again #231f20. The same happens when you hover off. I apologize for my horrible explanation.

Comment: I think you're a bit off with what you think is happening, I've changed all instances (just one actually) of `#231f20` to `orange` and what you say should be happening is not the case at all. See [**here**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/niaEc)

Comment: I understand you changed the instances. What I'm asking is to keep the integrity of my original pen, which used 2 colours. Here is the original article. The second example clearly shows 2 shades of blue. http://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeLinkEffects/

Comment: Here. The second colour I'm speaking of has been changed to blue in this new pen. http://codepen.io/Compton/pen/hlrId

Comment: Updated. See above answer.

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Thank you very much for your help. Again, sorry for being as clear as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to color all the span with a same color?

Edit the CSS:

```
/* Front Side */
.cl-effect-2 a span {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 14px;
    background-color: your_color; /* Edited CSS */
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
    transform-origin: 50% 0;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

/* Bottom Side */
.csstransforms3d .cl-effect-2 a:hover span::before,
.csstransforms3d .cl-effect-2 a:focus span::before {
    background-color:your_color; /* Edited CSS */   
}
```

**UPDATE:**
For different spans with different colors, please use classes, add the classes to the spans, like red, green or blue.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<section> <!--class="color-4"-->
<nav class="cl-effect-2">
<a href="#"><span class="red" data-hover="Option 1">Option 1</span></a>
<a href="#"><span class="blue" data-hover="Option 2">Option 2</span></a>
<a href="#"><span class="green" data-hover="Option 3">Option 3</span></a>
<a href="#"><span  class="red" data-hover="Option 4">Option 4</span></a>
<a href="#"><span class="green" data-hover="Option 5">Option 5</span></a>
<a href="#"><span class="blue" data-hover="Option 6">Option 6</span></a>
</nav>
</section>
</div><!-- /container -->
```

CSS:

```
.red{background-color:red !important;}
.green{background-color:green !important;}
.blue{background-color:blue !important;}

/* !important is needed to override the previous CSS.*/

.cl-effect-2 a span.red::before,
.cl-effect-2 a:hover span.red::before,
.cl-effect-2 a:focus span.red::before {
    background-color: red;  
}
.cl-effect-2 a span.green::before,
.cl-effect-2 a:hover span.green::before,
.cl-effect-2 a:focus span.green::before {
    background-color: green;    
}
.cl-effect-2 a span.blue::before,
.cl-effect-2 a:hover span.blue::before,
.cl-effect-2 a:focus span.blue::before {
    background-color: blue; 
}
```

Edited [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/asjob).

Comment: Don't be sorry. I'd like each span(button) a different colour. Not all spans the same colour.